# Split a string into two parts by using word

Tags: c#, .net

I would like to split directory into two parts:

For example

`//Hello//Products//App//Images//Room//40//Tulips.jpg`

into

`//Hello//Products//App`

and

`//Images//Room..40//Tulips.jpg`

Comment: Welcome to SO. This is not the type of questions that are posted and get answered here. You have to express a minimal effort of solving a well defined problem instead of aksing us to solve your not well described problem.

Comment: Ok. Did you have a question?

Comment: Sounds simple enough.  Did you have a question?  What have you tried and how is your attempt not working?

Comment: by which rule do you want to split?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var splitOn = "App";
var path = "//Hello//Products//App//Images//Room//40//Tulips.jpg";

var parts = path.Split(new string[] { splitOn }, StringSplitOptions.None);
Console.WriteLine(parts[0] + splitOn);
Console.WriteLine(parts[1]);
```

In order to split by a word (or in this case folder) you need to wrap the term in a string array before passing it to the String.Split function.  Splitting on "App" will also remove "App" from the result, so we concatenate it again before we write it to the console.

Answer (score 0):

First split the string based on the double forward slash and then assign to array.

```
string path= Hello//Products//App//Images//Room//40//Tulips.jpg
string[] names = path.Split('//');
```

After this collect the words like this:-

```
string first_part=names[0] + "//" + names[1];
```